# Iframe source inside a hugo shortcode

Tags: iframe, hugo, hugo-shortcode

I created a custom shortcode which includes an iframe to another static file of my blog. Something like this:

```
<iframe class="map" type="text/html" width="100%" src="/somefile.html?param={{ index .Params 0 }}" allowfullscreen frameborder="0">
```

The actual content is in the iframe src. I am trying to understand the best practice of where to put this file (`somefile.html` in the example above). Right now, it's under my `static` folder but I feel it would make more sense to keep it "closer" to the shortcode definition itself, especially if I want to share the shortcode with others.

Is there a way to make this work, i.e. reference a static html file within a shortcode template?

I considered using `srcdoc` but I couldn't figure out how to escape the quotes inside the html properly.

On a related note, is there a way to reference resources (like a stylesheet) from within the iframe source?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I define the source url in the front matter for the page the iframe is contained within

```
---
iframeSource: "target_asset_name"
---
```

Then use it as such:

```
{{- $srcurl := (print .Site.BaseURL "iframe_assests_root/" .Params.iframeSource "/") -}}
<iframe src="{{- $srcurl -}}"></iframe>
```

in that way you can put it wherever you want (I put in `assets/iframe_assets_root`)

Another option would be to put in a folder in `assets/` i.e.
`assets/iframesources/`, and use [page resources](https://gohugo.io/content-management/page-resources/) tools à la

```
{{- $ifsrc := resources.Get "iframesources/myiframe.html" -}}
<iframe src="{{- $ifsrc.Permalink -}}"></iframe>
```